# Question regarding STM32 timer trigger mode for synchronization

Tags: stm32, timer, synchronization

I am using STM32L4R5 and need a specific case of synchronization:

I am using TIM15 to generate a PWM signal with 50% duty cycle. In my application I have to stop PWM from time to time using the pin as GPIO so GPIO->AF and AF->GPIO changes are quite frequent. I could proceed with PWM only, changing the duty cycle to 0/100 for LOW/HIGH when necessary, but the problem is that I need synchronization for the PWM. After reading a lot of documents regarding synchronization using master/slave timer, I think the best option for me is to use the case with TIM15 in trigger mode, using TIM1 as master providing the trigger, both at same frequency/DC just TIM1 is constantly running and keeping the synchronization, TIM15 can be stopped when GPIO is necessary.
However, reading the explanations in the reference manual I am not sure how to pull it off.

The manual states that CEN bit of TIM15 will be automatically set when update event happens in TIM1. Thus, even if I disable the TIM15 my understanding is that it will be immediately started from TIM1 at next update event. My main ideas to test are:

1. Disable TIM15, change to GPIO for further tasks. If I can do it before the next update event from TIM1 would it be okay? Also, when I switch back to alternative function, I guess TIM15 will be started at the next available UEV from TIM1. Is this correct and is there something I have to be careful about here?
2. Once TIM15 is triggered, I will update the TS in the TIM15_SMCR register to unused TIM16/17 changing the trigger source to prevent automated CEN set. Then I will disable TIM15. When I need to start it again, it should be enough to set again TS field back to TIM1 and its next UEV will start the timer.

I will be happy if you can share any problems in the above solutions to choose the most suitable one, or propose some other clean idea.

Comment: If you only want off,50% and on why not toggle gpio on timer overflow/compare? You either stop the timer on the state you want or let it run.